# If dynamic table exists in the database Drop the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table which gets created Dynamically every 1st of a month. something like test201711 for November.

I want to check if test201711 exists in the DB Drop test201711

What I tried so far:

```
Declare @ste varchar(max)
set @ste = 'if exists (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where   TABLE_NAME =''test'+CONVERT(varchar(6),getdate(),112) + ''');'  + ' Drop table test'+ CONVERT(varchar(6),getdate(),112)
print @ste   
exec(@ste)
```

When I am printing the query it is correct, but when I am executing it is giving me an error.

What is wrong with my code here??

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use like this. It works for me.

```
-- Create the table for testing
CREATE TABLE Test201711
(
    id INT
)

SELECT NAME
FROM   sys.tables AS t
WHERE  t.name = 'Test201711'

DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100) = 'Test' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), GETDATE(), 112)

IF OBJECT_ID(@TableName) IS NOT NULL
    EXEC ('DROP Table ' + @TableName)

SELECT NAME
FROM   sys.tables AS t
WHERE  t.name = 'Test201711'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the problem is the semicolon.

```
Declare @ste nvarchar(max);
set @ste = '
if exists (select *
           from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
           where TABLE_NAME = ''[tablename]''
          )
     Drop table [tablename]
';
set @ste = replace(@ste, '[tablename]', CONVERT(varchar(6), getdate(), 112));
print @ste  

exec sp_executesql @ste;
```

Notes:

- This constructs the table name once and then uses `replace()` to put that into the query string.
- The semicolon at the end of the `if` is removed.
- Use `sp_executesql`.  It is much more powerful than `exec()`, even if parameters are not useful in this case.

You can also do this with a `try`/`catch` block:

```
begin try
    drop table [tablename]
end try
begin catch
    -- assume table doesn't exist and ignore error
end catch;
```

Comment: It is giving an error Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.